# Protocol Violation Exception when using WebClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, webclient

I am getting a Protocol Violation Exception : Content-Length or Chunked Encoding cannot be set for an operation that does not write data. I am not understanding why I am getting that error and how I could resolve. Can anyone help me on this regard. The exception is being thrown on the third line of the code.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
var resultjson = client.UploadString("" + _mvcurl + "Contact/GetContact",   //Get Contact Info
                                             serId);
```

I am using webforms which communicates with MVC Services method which checks the for authorization. The method in MVC app code is as below

```
[Authorize]
public JsonResult GetContact(Guid contactId)
{
    var result = GetContactServiceClient().GetContactById(contactId);
    return Json(result);
}
```